# On lambda calculus notation: FGa

Tags: lambda-calculus, notation

If we've got this expression:

> **FGa**

where **F** and **G** are functions (as well as **a**, of course; but let's treat **a** as a constant).

It must be understood that:
first apply **F** taking **G** as input; then apply the previous result with **a** as input. This is

> FGa = (FG)a

conventionally expressed:

> ( F(G) )( a )

Or is it this instead:

> **FGa** == **F(Ga)** == **F(G(a))**

Thanks.

Comment: According to function composition rules, $F\circ G \circ a = F(G(a))$. I don't know if this applies to lambda calculus as well, but my best guess is that it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first one. Function application is left-associative.

$$FGa = (F G) a$$